# extended forms in java

Tags: java, forms, netbeans7.0

I have this form where there are extendable controls like there's a textbox for the user to type and beside it is an add button which the user would use to add another textbox beneath the previous one.

My problem is i don't even know how to make that add button work so that another textarea/textbox would appear just beneath the previous control..im doing it in netbeans ide 7.0 and in design mode...

I have researching for quite a while now and i'm so confused already what to do..at least you could provide me with an idea not really the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Layout.

For your case (Form kinda layout) , it seems that you need GridLayout.

For example, please check this [link for all type of layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or directly go to [Grid Layout link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to be dynamically adding controls to your form, you'd simply want to put in a panel where you want the textbox and the button. Inside that panel place your textbox and button, you'd probably not want to use netbeans to do this, and use a LayoutManager like GridLayout. Now you'lld want to connect your button to an ActionListener that adds a textfiield to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) for an example of (amongst other things) adding components to a GUI dynamically.

[image]